# SignalR's $.hubConnection() not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm trying to implement a chat module in an ASP.NET MVC 4 application based on [an example over here](http://geekswithblogs.net/jeroenb/archive/2011/12/14/signalr-starter-application.aspx). Since this one's not using the latest SignalR version (0.5.3), I had to tweak the code to make it work.

Problem is, I couldn't even get the hubConnection to work. I'm encountering a JS error that says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    } has no method 'hubConnection'
```

I'm not sure why there's no hubConnection method. I have the latest jQuery and SignalR libraries, and I just followed the SignalR 0.5.3 release notes [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/announcing-the-release-of-signalr-0-5-3.aspx). Here's a snippet of the generated code in my View:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var connection = $.hubConnection();
        var chatHubClient = connection.createProxy("chatHub");

        connection.start(function () {
            chatHubClient.join('TEST');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hope someone can point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume you followed the walkthrough that came with 0.5.3's announcement already? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/announcing-the-release-of-signalr-0-5-3.aspx

make sure you can open both /Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.js and /signalr/hubs in a browser.

Comment: Yes, I followed that one. I can also open those two script files in the browser.

Comment: @Marco is the version number at the top of both scripts correct?

Comment: Yes. Both of them are the latest, if I may add.

Comment: I managed to setup the sample up until the Join method which has build errors. However when run it gets further than you managed.

You're not calling jquery noConflict anywhere are you?

do you have any other javascript libraries included?

Comment: Now I know where I went wrong. Even though I already imported jQuery in my chat page, I forgot that I added jQuery previously at the bottom of _Layout.cshtml (so that it will be imported in all pages). The second import nullifies whatever SignalR does to the jQuery object. Thanks for the help, Betty!

Comment: @Marco Did that too, forgot to put my scripts into the Scripts section, d'oh!

Comment: @Betty the link is not working

Comment: @YahyaHussein it is from 9 years ago, it's probably not that relevant to your problem. Maybe ask a new question.